# Initiliasing a character array in C when using structures and functions

Tags: c, function, struct, structure

I did a program to understand the concept of structures and returning struct from a function

```
struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char subject[20];
    int marks;
    int rollno;
}sheet;
struct student display()
{

    sheet.name[20]="Swathi";
    sheet.age=21;
    sheet.subject[20]="Mathematics";
    sheet.marks=85;
    printf("Enter roll no.:");
    scanf("%d",&sheet.rollno);

}
int main()
{   
    struct student sheet1;
    sheet1=display();
    printf("Name:%s",sheet.name);
    printf("Age:%d",sheet.age);

}
```

I am getting 2 warning messages

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  sheet.name[20]="Swathi";
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  sheet.subject[20]="Mathematics";
```

Why is it happening? How should I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here:

```
sheet.name[20]="Swathi";
```

Just gets the address of `"Swathi"` (which is read only), implicitly casts that address to a `char` (making it useless), and then assigns that to `sheet.name[20]` (which is out of bounds, so undefined behavior). Instead, try this:

```
strcpy(sheet.name, "Swathi");
```

Likewise with `sheet.subject[20]="Mathematics";`. Also note that your `struct student display()` isn't returning anything, it should be `void display()` and `struct student sheet1;` isn't needed.

Comment: Rather than posting yet another answer to this very common FAQ, consider close-voting it. A list of suitable dupe targets can be found in the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).

Answer (score 0):

It worked

```
struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char subject[20];
    int marks;
    int rollno;
}sheet;
struct student display()
{

    strcpy(sheet.name, "Swathi");
    sheet.age=21;
    strcpy(sheet.subject,"Mathematics");
    sheet.marks=85;
    printf("Enter roll no.:");
    scanf("%d",&sheet.rollno);

}
int main()
{   
    display();
    printf("Name:%s",sheet.name);
    printf("Age:%d",sheet.age);

}
```